# $x\ln(x)y'+y = xe^x$ solve $y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

the question is as above. I used multiply both sides by the integrating factor I(x) and integrate both sides, but this method doesn't work, is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If $x>0$ just multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$
$$\ln(x)y'+\frac1xy=e^x$$
Which is equivalent to
$$\frac{d}{dx}[y\ln(x)]=e^x$$
Then, integration give us
$$y\ln(x)=e^x+C,\qquad x>0$$